# Does yammer allow us to add plugins/add-ons to extend yammer functionality?

Tags: yammer

I am looking at ways to plug the content of our application into yammer. Does yammer provide a pluggable app framework to add stuff? One example would be: one-click share screen to start a discussion. I am looking and something similar to jive apps for example.

Answer (score 0):

The Yammer API and documentation for creating apps that can interact with Yammer is available at https://developer.yammer.com/. That's the extent of code samples that are available.

There are various ways of accessing the API, for example you can use Ruby and the yam gem at https://github.com/yammer/yam.